Keycloak 25.x.x Not Sending KC_RESTART Cookie
I'm currently using Keycloak 20.0.5 version which is working fine with following Dockerfile and YML file.
Dockerfile
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:25.0.0 as builder
WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:25.0.0
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/
RUN mkdir -p /opt/keycloak/themes/custom_theme
COPY ./custom_theme /opt/keycloak/themes/custom_theme
COPY ./sds-sms-authenticator-0.0.16.jar /opt/keycloak/providers/custom_provider.jar
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh"]

Deployment File
env:
- name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
  value: admin
- name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
  value: admin_password
- name: KC_PROXY
  value: edge
- name: KC_DB
  value: postgres
- name: KC_DB_URL
  value: jdbc:postgresql://sample.rds.amazonaws.com/sample_dev
- name: KC_DB_SCHEMA
  value: keycloak
- name: KC_DB_USERNAME
  value: db_app_user
- name: KC_DB_PASSWORD
  value: db_password
- name: KC_HEALTH_ENABLED
  value: "true"
- name: KC_METRICS_ENABLED
  value: "true"
- name: KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH
  value: /my-keycloak-service/

Public Ingress Configuration
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2024-07-11T07:25:56Z"
  generation: 3
  name: my-keycloak-public-ingress
  namespace: my
  resourceVersion: "200565111"
  uid: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
spec:
  ingressClassName: public-nginx
  rules:
  - host: xxx.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: my-keycloak-service
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /my-keycloak-service(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: xx.xxx.xx.xxx

Now I'm trying to migrate into Keycloak 25.x.x version and it's working fine in the localhost. However after entering admin login credentials, I'm getting following error page. As not sending KC_RESTART cookie in the http://xxx.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com/my-keycloak-service/realms/master/login-actions/authenticate request.
Even tried adding following ENV variables to the Dockerfile
ENV KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
ENV KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=true
ENV KC_HTTP_ENABLED=false


UPDATE
As per the following screenshot, browser receives cookies as the response of http://xxx.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com/sales-and-distribution-keycloak-service/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth before entering the user credentials.

However, browser doesn't save any cookies as per the following screenshot.


Appreciate if you can provide a solution or guide to troubleshoot further on this issue.
Thank you in advance!

Check your browser developer tools. Did your browser receive any cookie at all? Did your browser persist cookies? Did your browser sent those cookies after entering the admin login credentials?

@Manuel, I've updated the question. Yes browser receives cookie, however it does not save and send those cookies.

I guess:
Your browser does receive, but not persist the cookies from the HTTP response, as you dont use httpS to communicate with keycloak.

But it is working in the localhost with HTTP

Browsers differentiate between "localhost, 127.0.0.1", and actual external URLs.
